# Problems with if statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a simple javascript that will check if a variable is empty and if it is empty assign a random string to the variable

I have some code but it just keeps showing as null when the variable is empty instead of the random script

```
var myId = getParameterByName('check');

// The functions

if (myId) 
{ 
    var myId = function  () 
    {
        return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2);
    }
}
```

The expected result is if check is =5 then the variable myId should equal 5, if check equals null or empty then the myId variable should be a random string

Comment: You are 1) redeclaring `myId` (ditch the 2nd `var`) 2) assigning the function to it, not the result. `if (!myId) myId = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
var id1, id2 = 0, id3 = 'something', id4 = false;

function getParameterByName(varToCheck){
  if(varToCheck != undefined && varToCheck != null){
    return varToCheck;
  } else {
    return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2);
  }
}

console.log(getParameterByName(id1)); // Outputs a random string
console.log(getParameterByName(id2)); // Outputs 0 as it exists (is falsy but exists)
console.log(getParameterByName(id3)); // Outputs "something"
console.log(getParameterByName(id4)); // Outputs false
```

Comment: Thank AsomN yes it worked perfectly thank you very much :)

Comment: No problem - If it's what you expected please accept it as an answer.